# Cosa significa "fusa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Immobile tra le lenzuola sgualcite, mi rendo conto che sto fuggendo, non solo da Villaforesta ma anche da una vita di finzione di una noia irridemibile; da un'immagine di me che mi hanno cucita addosso, che credevo **fusa** come l'uniforme del soldatino di piombo e che invece scopro d'improvviso, non andarmi più bene. Anzi, stringe e fa male.

Ho cercato il [significato di "fuso" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fuso_res-af3a0465-001d-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/), ma non riesco a capire il significato di "fusa come l'uniforme del soldatino di piombo" in questo brano. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Participio passato di *fondere*. `;-)` Non un verbo facile da indovinare, eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I soldatini di piombo sono fusi in un pezzo unico; anche l'uniforme fa parte della fusione e quindi non è separabile dal corpo del soldatino.

Nel contesto del romanzo, una possibile rielaborazione:

> Immobile tra le lenzuola sgualcite, mi rendo conto che sto fuggendo,
>   non solo da Villaforesta ma anche da una vita di finzione di una noia
>   irridemibile; da un'immagine di me che mi hanno cucita addosso, che
>   credevo **parte integrante di me** come l'uniforme del soldatino di piombo e che invece
>   scopro d'improvviso, non andarmi più bene. Anzi, stringe e fa male.

In questo contesto fusa è da interpretare come: facente parte di me, non distinta e quindi non separabile.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!